# Linux user name in script

Tags: php, linux, security

I'm a total newb to security, so I have a really simple question:

Is it a security hazard to include the full path to my user directory in an open-source script?

I mean like `include '/home/myusername/script.php'`

Thanks!

Comment: do you know about setting the include path?

Comment: yes but i was avoiding modifying my php settings. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not totally a security hazard, as your username is not necessarily expected to be a secret. But if you want it to work for lots of people and avoid this problem at the same time, use the $HOME env var instead.

EDIT: Whoops, sorry assumed this was a bash script. Don't know if you can access env vars from PHP and whether your 'import' paths can use them, so you can ignore that second part, but the first part is still valid.

Comment: thanks! i didnt think to use an environment variable! i had to use getenv though instead of $_ENV